# What is the key difference between the term "Research Gaps" and the terms "Literature Survey" or "Literature Review"?

Tags: literature-review

The difference between the terms "Literature Survey" and "Literature Review" is covered in [this question and answers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15080/20058). But how do they differ from "Research Gaps" in the context of a research proposal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between "Literature review" and "Literature survey" is small, if it exists at all - people may use the two terms to mean the same thing. It has been discussed in [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/literature-review-versus-literature-survey-what-is-the-difference).

A "research gap" is an area of research that has not yet been done. You may *identify* a research gap by doing a literature review or survey.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.